# How do I get full messages and attachments from my Gmail inbox using an API?

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I want to download an entire inbox (email body text and attachments) from my Gmail. Using message IDs, I can get `Gmail.Message` objects, but these only appear to contain snippets (about 200 characters).

For C#, is there a way to get the whole inbox in XML format using the Gmail API?

Comment: What is the API call you make exactly? Can you provide the HTTP Request please?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API you would need to make a request to `/users/me/threads` then to `users/me/threads/<id>`within that response there is a `body.data` value that is base 64 encoded. I am not 100% sure with the c# API but i assume that you would do something like:

```
var request = service.Users.Threads.List("me");

var labels = request.Execute().Threads;
foreach(var thread in lables){
    var threadReqeust = service.Users.Threads.Get("me", thread.Id);
    var data = threadReqeust.Execute();
    //you have your entire message now
}
```

***(do take note that this is semi pusudo code, as i have not checked this with the gmail api)***

(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list)
(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get)
"An attachment ID is present if the body data is contained in a separate attachment."

Another option is to always login with IMAP (using ImapX or equivalent), and collect data that way, but using the API would be better.

Comment: Its a way i was following. But there is no field "body" only "snippet"

Comment: Try looking at the Format Property in the request (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) 

Also the list (of messages) within the thread item (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads#resource-representations)

Comment: How to configure the Format Property? I found Format property:  
var getReq = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full;

But how to use method Get? I have to use service. Right? service.Users.Messages.Get("me", item.Id).Execute() - but method get dont have any overloads with the third parameter like Format.

Answer (score 0):

For gmail API please refer to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#parameters

**HTTP request**

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages

Make sure you are applying correct authorization headers on your requests.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#request), you can use

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id`

Is this the call you are using? It says the default format is `Full` :

> "full": Returns the full email message data with body content parsed in the payload field; the raw field is not used. (default)

For getting attachments you can try 
[Users.messages.attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) :

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/messageId/attachments/id`

But for this you will need the attachment ID. You may want to check the [User.messages overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages), which shows the available data, maybe you can try the `Payload` calls?